# Source of: Two Doors with Two Guards - 1 lies 1 tells the truth riddle?

Tags: puzzle-creation, puzzle-history

I am looking for the source to the riddle that involved 
two doors: safety/destruction
two guards: one always lies/one always tells the truth
time for a single question from a single gaurd.

I first heard and solved this riddle when taking philosophy 101: an intro to logic at Ohio State University back in 1983.

I was surprised to find that they had a problem I'd never heard before as there wern't that many good logic proplems going around back then.

Riddles often have clues to their source,ie based on the conservation of matter so the source may have been from a physics professors lecture.

The riddle under question is based on truth tables or possibly multiples of pos/neg numbers

Does any one have any clues to it's source?
has anyone heard it before 1983?

thanks

Comment: well in 1986 it was in a movie called; labyrinth.

Comment: A variant of this puzzle appears in Part 4 of the Doctor Who serial [The Pyramids of Mars](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Pyramids_of_Mars_(TV_story)) which first aired in 1975.

Answer (score 6):

The common name for such types of puzzles is a [Knights and Knaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_and_Knaves) puzzle (named by [Raymond Smullyan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_Smullyan) in a book from 1978) or just a liars puzzle. The earliest I've found is Mathematical Recreations (1953) by [Maurice Kraitchik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurice_Kraitchik).

If you'd like to see some more, the [liars](/questions/tagged/liars) tag here has tons of them, including the exact [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2188/two-doors-with-two-guards-one-lies-one-tells-the-truth) you described.