# What's that puzzle that goes like: Person A never lies, Person B always lies, etc?

Tags: logical-deduction, puzzle-identification

What's the name of the puzzle where you're given something like:

> Person A never lies. Person B always lies. Person C I don't remember.

Then it continues like:

> Person A says that person B is lying.
>   Person B says that person C is wrong.

Comment: Knights and knaves?

Comment: http://philosophy.hku.hk/think/logic/knights.php

Answer (score 2):

As the comments have mentioned, I believe the puzzle is most commonly called knights and knaves, with knights always telling the truth and knaves always lying.

There are many variations from the original, however.. Ranging from adding other types of behaviors (e.g.. random), having multiple characters give testimonies and you have to guess who's lying and who's telling the truth, etc. For these kind of questions you can check the [liars](/questions/tagged/liars) tag in this SE.

I believe it's going to be *very* difficult to pinpoint a specific version unless it's one of the original ones - there's like hundreds to thousands of liars puzzles out there.

Comment: See [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2188/two-doors-with-two-guards-one-lies-one-tells-the-truth) for the classic 2 doors with 2 guards puzzle.