# Riddle Again, Riddle Again, What am I?

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

1.

> If a chicken says, "All chickens are liars" is the chicken telling the truth?

2.

> A man is traveling to a town and comes to a fork in the road. If he goes left, he goes to the liars' village. If he goes right, he then goes to the village of truths - which is where he wants to go. However, he does not know which way is which. 
>  He doesn't have time to go both routes, so he approaches a stranger who is standing in the middle of the fork. The stranger says he may only ask 3 questions and he will answer them. 
>  The man asks, "Are you from the village of truths?" The stranger says, "Yes!" However, the man is still facing a dilemma: If the stranger was from the village of truths he can only tell the truth, but if he was from the village of liars, he would say he was from the village of truth. 
>  So then he asks the stranger, "Are you telling the truth?" The stranger says, "Yes!" But sadly this leaves the man in the same position as before.
>
> Can you figure it out ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two doors with two guards - one lies, one tells the truth](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2188/two-doors-with-two-guards-one-lies-one-tells-the-truth)

Comment: I mean that u should not post too many questions (once or twice a day). This is just a suggestion so that u can spend some time making a good riddle or questions. Btw, if u post a riddle here that is from another source, include a link or something :)

Comment: The first question reminds me of this: *A barber shaves those who do not shave themselves; he also does not shave those who do shave themselves. What happens when the barber shaves himself?*

Comment: Well, he probably won't shave himself right? @user477343

Comment: @KevinL hahah, yeah. Most people say it's a paradox. But the answer is: nothing at all! The barber doesn't have to shave himself. It's a pretty easy one, but I always liked it :D

Answer (score 5):

1.

> The chicken obviously cannot be telling the truth. However, he could be lying. Not all chickens are liars. Some are liars, some are honest. This chicken just so happens to be a liar.

2.

> Ask the man "where would someone from the other village tell me to turn to go to the village of truth". Go the opposite way. This can be rephrased to a yes/no question if need be. "Would a person from the other village tell me to turn left to go to the village of truths?"

Comment: oh didn't see that :)

Comment: That explanation for no.1 is crafty :P

Answer (score 4):

1.

> If the chicken is saying the truth, then all chickens must lie (Contradicts one another) 
>  If the chicken is lying, then all chickens must tell the truth (contradicts one another) 
>  **NO CONCLUSION**

2.

> Super simple. Just ask him to go back to his real village. If he was from the village of truth, you can follow him there. If he was a liar, he will still go to the village of truth in which you can also still follow him there

Answer (score 1):

My answer at number 1:

> Neither true nor false

Why?

> Assumption 1: True. 
>  The chicken is a liar, which the statement is true, so it is a contradiction. 
>  
>  Assumption 2: False. 
>  The chicken tells the truth, which the statement is false, so it is a contradiction.