# Fork in the road problem - with a single person

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

You walk to a fork from where two roads come out - one leading to a post office and the other to a university.

You want to go to the university, but do not know which road would lead you to it. A sentry standing on the fork knows the answer, but he has a habit of alternately speaking the truth and telling a lie.

**What single question to the sentry will help you find the right road?**

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Just wondering, did you write this puzzle yourself, or is it from a book/test/somewhere else?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Well....I was looking into some past questions of my varsity and found this. But I'm unaware of the fact that which professor made it ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a variant of the classical [two roads, two guards problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2188/5373), except that

> two different guards (one telling the truth, one lying) is replaced by two different statements by the same guard (one truth, one lie).

So the question should be:

> If my next question will be "does *this* road lead to the post office", what will you say?

The sentry has a habit of alternately speaking the truth and telling a lie, so:

- If his answer now is the truth, then

  > his next statement will be a lie, so he will give you the false answer that he *would* give for the next question.
- If his answer now is a lie, then

  > his next statement will be truthful, so he will lie and give you the false answer now.

Either way, you've got your answer

> about whether that road leads to the post office - which, since it's false, you take as the answer about whether it leads to the university.